# Timestamp of Outlook emails using Python

Tags: python, email, outlook, timestamp, win32com

Is it possible to use Python to extract timestamps from received email?  I'm using the following code but to no avail:

```
messages = ap.Items
message = messages.GetNext()
receipt = message.ReceivedTime.date()  

for i in messages:
    print(receipt)
```

I only get one date published repeatedly for each email.  (i.e., 2021-11-22, 2021-11-22, 2021-11-22.......)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, of course - you only retrieve `ReceivedTime` once:

```
for i in messages:
    print(i.ReceivedTime.date())
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed... (still learning).  Thank you